# storing multiple user String input into an Array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code. I need to store `EmployeeNumber` and `Name` into an `Array`. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{   
    int numEmps = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter Employee number: ");
    employeeNumber = sc.nextLine();
    numEmps++;
    System.out.print("Enter Employee name: ");
    name = sc.nextLine();
    numEmps++;

    employees[numEmps] = new Employee(employeeNumber, name, role, level);
}
```

Comment: how `Employee` look like?

Answer (score 2):

**First** You have to use `int numEmps = 0;` outside your loop :

```
int numEmps = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
  ...
}
```

In your case you put all employees in the `employees[2]`

**Second** you have to use only one `numEmps++;`

---

Your code should look like :

```
int numEmps = 0;//<<------------------------------------------Problem 1
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter Employee number: ");
    employeeNumber = sc.nextLine();
    //numEmps++;<<--------------------------------------------Problem 2
    System.out.print("Enter Employee name: ");
    name = sc.nextLine();
    numEmps++;

    employees[numEmps] = new Employee(employeeNumber, name, role, level);
    //          ^^------------------You can avoid to use numEmps, instead you can use i
}
```

---

**Note** like @Le Duy Khanh mention in comment, you ca use `employees[i]` instead of using a new variable

Comment: why don't just use employees[i]? then no need numEmps++;

Comment: @LeDuyKhanh we don't see the other part of code so we don't know what the OP want to do with `numEmps` but your suggest is also correct i will edit my answer

Comment: then your ans should be numEmps = [some_value_to_start]

Comment: and what i said in the first problem @LeDuyKhanh did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here you store these two information in an array of `Employee`.
It seems fine.
Before the loop, you should declare the array :

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[5];
```

Besides in the loop you don't need to use `numEmp` (you increment twice by the way, which is not suitable) as you have already the `int i` value that you declare in the loop. So, just use `i` as index of the element added in the array.

And this should be enough :

```
employees[i] = new Employee(employeeNumber, name);
```

as you don't specify the value of `role` and `level` in your requirement and in your code.

Ideally,    `employeeNumber = sc.nextLine();` should be converted to a numeric value(`int number = Integer.valueOf(employeeNumber)`) if you want to represent employeeNumber as a number (for example an int or a long).

Answer (score 0):

since you are increasing the  numEmps variable twice on every loop iteration then your array is getting filled every 2 elements...

Answer (score 0):

Put `int numEmps = 0;` out of your `for` loop.

This will be re-initialized to zero every time looped.

Answer (score 0):

```
int numEmps = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
   System.out.print("Enter Employee number: ");

   employeeNumber = sc.nextLine();

   numEmps++;
   System.out.print("Enter Employee name: ");

   name = sc.nextLine();

   numEmps++;

   employees[numEmps] = new Employee(employeeNumber, name, role, level);
}
```

Use your variable `numEmps` outside the `for` loop, otherwise in every iteration it is becoming `0` again.